# Why is there two “the” before the “annual meeting” in the sentence “”?

Tags: articles

The original sentence is "That, at least, is the hope of a panel of researchers who presented their work to the the annual meeting of the American Association for the Advantage of Science, in Austin, Texas. " ([The Economist 22.02.2018 'Using domestic animals to make human organs'](https://www.economist.com/news/science-and-technology/21737245-mix-and-match-using-domestic-animals-make-human-organs)).

I just modify the sequence of the words for easy read:

At least, that is the hope of a panel of researchers who presented their work to the the annual meeting of the American Association for the Advantage of Science, in Austin, Texas.

I am confused why there are two articles "the" before the word "annual".
is it a clerical error or a proper way?

Comment: Seems like a typo to me.

Comment: Because I use the Economist as my English studying materials for IELTS test, I just wonder whether the Economist, a known English Magazine, will make a mistake in their publication such as the typo. What other high-quality magazines do you recommend?

Comment: I was hoping another member would help you out as I don't subscribe to any magazines. Have you checked out something like the Wall Street Journal? I think they are pretty legitimate.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

It's a typo—it should be just *the*, not *the the*.

It doesn't matter how good the author, editor, or publisher. Mistakes will *always* happen at some point. You can expect that the better the author, editor, and publisher, the fewer the number of mistakes will be made. But no person or system is perfect.